# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: spring, jpa, struts2, java-ee-6

I'm integrating Spring 3+ JPA + Struts 2

i'm getting the following error

> 22:07:48,527 ERROR [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0'
>   defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]:
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation
>   of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings.(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/List;Lorg/hibernate/cfg/NamingStrategy;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/Map;)V
>   from class org.hibernate.cfg.ExtendedMappings  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:410)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3856)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4361)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:790)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:770)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:553) 
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:296)
>   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
>   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659) 
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5312)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:296)
>   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
>   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659) 
>   at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:301)
>   at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:104)
>   at
>   org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:375) 
>   at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)  at
>   org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)  at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
>   at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659) 
>   at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
>   at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417) 
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659) 
>   at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)  at
>   $Proxy44.start(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:466)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
>   at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
>   at
>   org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
>   at
>   org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:87)
>   at
>   org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
>   at
>   org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659) 
>   at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)  at
>   $Proxy45.start(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)  at
>   org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)  at
>   org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)  at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
>   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659) 
>   at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)  at
>   $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
>   at
>   org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:610)
>   at
>   org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
>   at
>   org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.loop(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:274)
>   at
>   org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.run(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:225)

I'm not getting what is the Issue ?

Thank You

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't specify the point-cut, so that injection happens for that respective class .

Comment: How you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't providing enough information, but from what I see I can suggest to upgrade your jar versions to newest/compatible with each other versions. Note that JBoss comes with hibernate bundled, so you'd need to either remove all hibernate and JPA jars from your app, or tell JBoss to pick your jars instead of the bundled one.